# Is it difficult for Filipina to be allowed admission into US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, filipino-citizens

OK, I have to follow guide lines and put a separate question for each post.

So here goes again.

My Filipina girlfriend wants to visit US, well to be frank, she wants to live with me in the US, but I already told her in emails that I she can visit me but I am still going to go to her country, marry her and apply for K-3 spousal Visa.

Originally, I was going to do this in a traditional manner by going to her country first, meeting the family and so on but after how she got sick with dengue and the only thing I could do was send her money, I decided to follow her wishes first and try to have her visit me first. My plan is for us to be here in America for approximately 5 months.

Of course, I am the one financing everything, including paying for her home in her country, I do not have a house here, so other than the fact that I have a child from my first marriage, I have no actual strong ties to America but we all know that proof of strong ties to the US Embassy in any country is difficult to prove to them.

Still going to marry her, but do not know if I will just move to her country or sponsor her to come to America but I have heard about how harsh the CBP officers are towards foreigners and even if they aren't a threat, they will consider a young woman, who is coming to see a friend, with a high possibility of trying to live in America and may possibly deny admission.

So my question is what is the likelihood of my girlfriend being denied admission into America, rather the case of her arriving to America alone or both of us arriving into America together?

Comment: That is very hard to answer as it depends on the impression you and her would make on the immigration officer and such is hardly answerable. I have flagged this question as primarily opinion-based, but others may disagree. It might be helpful if you could edit your question to include information on how and where you met?

Comment: No offense, but even though I trust her, the more I see answers such as it could be a scam, it makes me want to follow the more traditional method of meeting her at least once, but best to make multiple trips and to give it more time. As passion and trust does not build up the security in a relationship that time will bring.

Comment: As Ronald Reagan said, "Trust, but verify."

Comment: Whoa, that is a very powerful statement and thank you for the comment.

Comment: @mts Perhaps it is opinion-based, but adjusting to ask for statistics of refusal might make it salvageable?

Comment: Didn't think of that, and thank you. However, I will just meet her first, put funds in her bank account over a period of time then have her travel here.

Comment: "after how she got sick with dengue and the only thing I could do was send her money," - ***THIS IS A SCAM UNLESS*** you have **actually, already** met her in person.

Comment: **My alarm bells are going off**: if I understand you correctly, you have never met her; she canceled your trip to go visit her then you sent her money supposedly for dengue treatment; also you plan to buy her a home in the Philippines and 'pay for everything', even though you still haven't met her. Be aware that foreigners have no right to own property in the Philippines; she might have five other online boyfriends also buying properties for her; it might be a scam (e.g. to earn commission from real estate). Be very skeptical, stop sending $$, and see if her ardor for you suddenly cools.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a US citizen, your own ties to the country are irrelevant: you have the absolute right of entry to the US.

We can't predict whether an immigration officer would allow your girlfriend into the US, or whether she would be given a visa in the first place. However, the key criteria for a non-immigrant visitor visa are that the visitor will leave when they say they'll leave, and that they're able to support themself during their visit.

The usual way to demonstrate that somebody is going to leave is that they have strong ties to the country they'll be going back to: for example, a job and a home. So, the obvious question here is whether somebody who has strong ties to their home country is able to take a five-month break on the other side of the world to visit somebody that they want to marry, despite never having met them.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for this answer. The information you have provided is very informative and I wish that the weeks of searching the net could have gave me an understanding as clear as you have given me. Again, thank you very much.  I am going to talk to her, have us come to a mutual understanding that it is best I at least visit her first. However, it is very frustrating how America is as Americans can leave the country when we please and marry in other countries no problem, many countries will easily accept Americans but in turn America pretty much spits in the face of outsiders.